# Why does ASH return 'Permission denied' when typing `..`?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, zsh

In ZSH, `..` is equivalent to `cd ..` thanks to `auto_cd`, which, if I had to guess (I'm totally guessing) is some kind of alias.

However, in many other `*sh`'es (`ash`, `bash` at least), this functionality is not implemented.

In `ash`, you get

```
willard@willardsworld:~/.ssh# ..
-ash: ..: Permission denied
```

which is wack. If I had to guess (again, guessing) it's a permissions error because `root` owns the directory.

```
willard@willardsworld:~/.ssh# ls -la
drwxr-xr-x    3 root     root          4096 May 22 16:06 .
drwxr-xr-x   21 root     root          4096 May 22 15:03 ..
drwx------    2 root     root          4096 May 26 11:37 .ssh
```

However, it still doesn't work as `root`.

```
root@willardsworld:~/.ssh# ..
-ash: ..: Permission denied
```

Which, again, is wack. `root` owns `..`, right?

Compare this behavior to `bash`, where you simply get

```
willard@willardsworld:~/.ssh$ ..
..: command not found
```

which totally makes sense. That functionality just doesn't exist.

What I'm wondering is, how does ZSH `auto_cd` work, and why does `ash` spit out a permission error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an educated guess about the cause, but here's what may be going on. When you use a command name that doesn't contain "`/`" (i.e. it's just a name, not an explicit path), the shell will check to see if it's an alias, function, or builtin, and if it's not any of those it'll look for it as an executable file in the directories in `$PATH`. So the process goes something like this:

1. Check whether "`..`" is an alias, function, or builtin: nope.
2. Say the first directory in `$PATH` is `/bin`. Check whether `/bin/..` exists in the filesystem: *yes it does*!

   Every directory contains an item named "`..`", which is a link to its parent directory in the filesystem, so `/bin/..` is a link to `/`.
3. Try to execute `/bin/..`, which fails because it's a directory not an executable file. (You can `cd` to a directory, but that's completely different from executing it.)

Now, this doesn't explain why you're getting a "Permission denied" error instead of some sort of "that's not an executable file" error, so I might be wrong. In `ash` on your OS, try running `/bin/..` as an explicit command and see what error message you get.

Comment: Well, what do you know?

`root@willardsworld:~/.ssh# /bin/..` returns 
`-ash: /bin/..: Permission denied`

Good guess! I might try looking through the syscalls to see if it follows the logic you proposed.

Answer (score 0):

Bash must be using some defensive programming where it identifies that ".." is a directory and so refuses to run it. ash, will just be calling execve(2) or similar and returning the resulting operating system error. The following 3 lines of C will emit "Permission denied":

```
    char *args[] = { "..", 0 };
    execve("..", args, 0);
    perror(0);
```

The man page for execve(2) lists a number of interpretations for EACCES.

The zsh feature is not implemented as an alias. alias expansion applies very early. It occurs along with the search for executable files. And if you do `unsetopt autocd`, it will print "permission denied".